# exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00e4df90

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm trying to build a function that takes a string and vector containing objects of a custom class as arguments and returns the element of the vector that has the same .name string member as the argument string. The function that I've written is as follows and works as long as I don't try to use the ingame "get object" feature on an item that doesn't exist. If I do that the program crashes with the run time error in the title. I'm not sure what is causing this error, could someone point out the mistake? I've tried making sure all the paths in string_to_item return an items type but that didn't work. Another interesting thing is that break never actually causes the for loop to stop, it just continues to the end.

```
items string_to_item( string item_name, const vector<items>& item_container ) {
    if ( item_container.size() > 0 ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < item_container.size(); ++i) {
            if ( item_container[i].name == item_name ) {
                return item_container[i];
                break;
            }
            else
                cout << "No such item found";
        }
    }

    else
        return items("null");

    if ( item_container.size() == 0) 
        cout << "no elements in vector  ( get_item )";
}
```

The debugger call stack points to this at the time of the crash:

```
KernelBase.dll!74b01d4d()
```

The other functions that calls this function and the class involved are:

```
void get(const vector<string>& input_tokens, vector<items>& global_item_list) {
        player_inventory.get_item( string_to_item( input_tokens[1], global_item_list) );
    cout << "You have picked up a " << input_tokens[1] << ".\n\n";
    remove_from_world( string_to_item( input_tokens[1], global_item_list), global_item_list);
}   

void inventory::get_item( items name ) {
        contents.push_back(name);
}

struct items {
    string name;
    char type;
    string description;
    items() {
        name = " ";
        type = ' ';
        description = " ";
    }
    items( string n )
        : name(n) {}
    items( string n, char t, string d )
        : name(n), type(t), description(d) {}
    bool operator()( const items& one, const items& two ) const {
        return one.name.compare(two.name) < 0;
    }
};

void remove_from_world( items full_def, vector<items>& global_item_list ) {
    vector<items>::iterator it = find( global_item_list.begin(), global_item_list.end(),full_def);
    int i = distance(global_item_list.begin(), it);
    if (it != global_item_list.end())
        global_item_list.erase(global_item_list.begin() + i);
else {
        cout << "remove from world failure";
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. They should be telling you that you reached the end of a function without returning a value.

Comment: Related: you may find [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) particularly useful in your item search, and throw out a not-insignificant amount of buggy code in the process. (your search loop is not good).

Comment: @WhozCraig - I would have liked to do that but since std::find iterates through the vector looking for a term of the same type as the kind in the vector and I'm trying to find the item by an identifier that's a string (by comparing it to a member object of the string type) I didn't know how to set it up. I hope that makes sense. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Beside your concrete problem you should think about using a std::map, e.g. map<string,item>

Comment: If you intend your `items` to be indexed by `name` , consider storing them in a `std::map<string, items>` or even a `std::set`. Then you replace all this code with one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not debugging your code since you shouldn't be writing loops like that for something as simple as locating an item in a container. Use an algorithm from `<algorithm>` and your problem will most likely disappear.

Since you're looking for an `items` object with a particular `name`, you need to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). The predicate you supply will do the job of comparing `item_name` to `items::name`.

With C++11 this is extremely easy, write a lambda expression that does the job.

```
items string_to_item( string item_name, const vector<items>& item_container )
{
    auto result = std::find_if(item_container.begin(), item_container.end(), 
                               [&](items const& it) {
                                   return it.name == item_name;
                               });
    if(result == item_container.end()) {
        if(item_container.size() == 0) {
            std::cout << "no elements in vector  ( get_item )";
        }
        return items("null");
    }

    return *result;
}
```

If you're using an older compiler, then the task becomes a bit more verbose. The easiest option is to create a functor that stores a reference to `item_name` and overloads `operator()` to perform the comparison. This is exactly what the compiler is doing behind the scenes in the C++11 version above.

```
struct comparer
{
    comparer(std::string const& item_name) : item_name(item_name) {}
    bool operator()(items const& it) const { return it.name == item_name; }
    std::string const& item_name;
};

items string_to_item( string item_name, const vector<items>& item_container )
{
    comparer comp(item_name);

    std::vector<items>::const_iterator result = 
        std::find_if(item_container.begin(), item_container.end(), comp);
    if(result == item_container.end()) {
        if(item_container.size() == 0) {
            std::cout << "no elements in vector  ( get_item )";
        }
        return items("null");
    }

    return *result;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcc3954b94694f8c)

Comment: Related: I cannot recall if C++11 support is required for template parameter types deduced from call-parameters where the *type* is local. I know it was a big pain in the ass until C++11, though some vendors (notably MS) broke the rules and allowed it even though the standard did not. If the pre-11 tool-chain the OP is using does *not* allow the second sample to compile for this reason, moving the decl of `comparer` (not the `comp` object, just its *type*). *outside* the function should work and takes little effort.  Nice answer, btw. +1.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good catch! I'd compiled both snippets with `-std=c++11` and missed the (silly) C++03 requirement that types used as template arguments must have external linkage. I even let an `auto` sneak in there :) Fixed now.